# How to get Intellisense on Visual Studio (VS) Code to work on Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have Visual Studio Code on my laptop and setting it up for the first time and am having trouble making Intellisense work. I downloaded the python extension. When I tried to type a syntax, I don't see a drop down of the available methods.

What I did so far was press F1> type 'open settings'> and see that the option is turned on. It looks like the setting is on, screenshot below line 18. I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing. Would anyone happen to have an idea of how I can have the auto complete functionality to work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense was provided by the Language Server, The default value of it is `Default`.

> Default: Automatically select a language server: Pylance if installed
> and available, otherwise fallback to Jedi.

So, it's a little weird of your problem, could you try to install the `Pylance`  and set it as the Language Server? Add this in the settings.json file:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: Hi Steven, appreciate the response! I tried your suggestion but was not able to download Pylance; see error image link https://imgur.com/IUiIzPV. I also tried adding the line of code into the settings.json file and tried again to download pylance but the same error came again.

Comment: @LeonCecil Can you update your VSCode?

Comment: @LeonCecil Help -> Check for updates

Comment: Ahh good tip! Let me try that out and get back to you on this. Busy day today...

Comment: You're the best it works now! I feel kinda dumb now, should had thought of this answer but I'll remember the next time!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Ctrl+Space` or hovering some code?
Also do you have "Visual Studio IntelliCode" extension installed?

If neither `Ctrl+Space` nor hovering work, it is recommended to restart VS Code (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_troubleshooting)

Comment: Hi Keyne, thanks for the response! I Tried your suggestion and CTRL+SPACE doesn't show any of the methods. The screenshot from my link shows that I'm trying to see the dropdown for p (for print syntax), but show's 'loading'. https://imgur.com/M6uV1It. Hovering over doesn't seem to show anything either. I also tried restarting VS code, restarting my computer, and even re-downloading VS Code but still no luck.